# jQuery multiple checkbox filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filter

I have a list of events, these events are each of a specific type, and start in a specific month. I have a checkbox group for types and one for months. What I'm trying to do is use the checkboxes to filter the list. I've got it working with one group, but can't seem to get it working with two.

Basically I'm trying to set a class when I hide the list item, so I know which group hid it, but it seems to get confused. The class names are correct but some sometimes items do not get shown again.

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong, or think of a better solution that would be great! Thanks!

Darren.

My JavaScript:

```
$("#options input.type_check").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass('type_hidden');
        if(!$("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).hasClass('start_hidden')) {
            $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideDown();
        }
    } else {
        $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('type_hidden');
        $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideUp();
    }
    return false;
});

$("#options input.start_check").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).removeClass('start_hidden');
        if(!$("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).hasClass('type_hidden')) {
            $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideDown();    
        }
    } else {
        $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('start_hidden');
        $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideUp();
    }
    return false;
});
```

My HTML:

```
<p>Types:</p>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_0" value="0" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_0">Type 0</label></div>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_1" value="1" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_1">Type 1</label></div>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_2" value="2" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_2">Type 2</label></div>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_3" value="3" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_3">Type 3</label></div>
<div><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" id="type_4" value="4" class="type_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_4">Type 4</label></div>

<p>Starts:</p>
<div><input name="start[]" type="checkbox" id="start_072009" value="072009" class="start_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_072009">July 2009</label></div>
<div><input name="start[]" type="checkbox" id="start_082009" value="082009" class="start_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_082009">August 2009</label></div>
<div><input name="start[]" type="checkbox" id="start_092009" value="092009" class="start_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_092009">September 2009</label></div>
<div><input name="start[]" type="checkbox" id="start_102009" value="102009" class="start_check" checked="checked" /><label for="type_102009">October 2009</label></div>

<p>Events</p>
<ul id="events">
    <li id="1768" class="type_0 start_072009">Event 1</li>
    <li id="2190" class="type_1 start_072009">Event 2</li>
    <li id="2191" class="type_2 start_072009">Event 3</li>
    <li id="1864" class="type_2 start_082009">Event 4</li>
    <li id="1679" class="type_3 start_082009">Event 5</li>
    <li id="2042" class="type_0 start_092009">Event 6</li>
    <li id="1717" class="type_4 start_092009">Event 7</li>
    <li id="1917" class="type_4 start_092009">Event 8</li>
    <li id="1767" class="type_4 start_092009">Event 9</li>
    <li id="1866" class="type_2 start_102009">Event 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: There's no CSS, see example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID attributes on your LIs are invalid - they can't be just numbers. Javascript will probably choke when trying to make assignments on them.

See the standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$("#options input.type_check").change(function() {
```

To this:

```
$("#options input.type_check").click(function() {
```

Make a similar change to your start_check selector.  This hooks the `click` event instead of the `change` event on your checkboxes.  This event will fire whether the mouse or the keyboard is used to alter the checkbox.

I tested it on my computer using IE7 and Firefox.

Comment: That still doesn't fix it. I've put up my example here: http://dev.darrenhall.info/temp/stackoverflow/jqueryfilter/

To break it, un-tick everything except indoor climbing, then un-tick all the months. When you re-tick the months, the events don't come back. Weird?!

Comment: They all come back if I untick indoor climbing, and tick it again.  That might be a clue...

Comment: Yeah, it's strange. I can tick and un-tick Jul - Sept and they don't come back, but Oct does come back.

Comment: I think your best bet is to load this thing up in Firebug and see what the functions are doing to your element classes.  I can't quite grok it by just looking at the code.

Comment: I have, for some reason when you un-tick Jul - Sept, the 'start_hidden' class is removed, but the display is not being set back to block.

Comment: Well, what is clear is that there is some kind of undesirable interaction between your two sections, because if you stay in one section you can click or unclick any combination and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes I know that! My question was, can anyone see why is it going wrong or if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the fix.  Change:

```
if(!$("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).hasClass('start_hidden')) {
    $("#events li."+$(this).attr('id')).slideDown();
}
```

to:

```
$("#events li).not(".type_hidden, .start_hidden").slideDown();
```

in both places.

Comment: Brilliant! I knew we'd get there in the end Thanks!